# Redirect with data back to where the form was completed laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form from which the controller gets the data requested from the db. I want to then redirect to the same page as the form but with the data i got from the db. I am using laravel 5.5

This is my controller for the store:

```
    public function listsStore(Request $request) {
        $data = $request->all();
        $user = $request->user;
        $day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->day));
        $from =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->from));
        $to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->to));
        $radio = $data['radio-btn'];

        // dd($user, $from, $to);
        // dd($radio);

        if($radio === 'tasks') {
            if($request->day) {
                $tasks = Task::where('user_id', $user)
                        ->whereDate('start', $day)
                        ->orderBy('start','DESC')
                        ->get();
                // dd($tasks);
                return redirect()->back()->with('tasks', $tasks);
            }else{ // gets for the range of dates requested
                $tasks = Task::where('user_id', $user)
                        ->whereBetween('start',[$from, $to])
                        ->orderBy('start','DESC')
                        ->get()
                        ->groupBy(function($date) {
                        return Carbon::parse($date->start)->format('Y-m-d'); 
                        });
                // dd($tasks);
                return redirect()->back()->with('tasks', $tasks);
            } 
        }elseif($radio === 'timecards'){ //IF REQUEST IS TIMECARDS
            if($request->day) { //gets for the day requested
                $timecards = Timecard::where('user_id',$user)
                            ->whereDate('checkin', $day)
                            ->orderBy('checkin','DESC')
                            ->get();
                // dd($timecards);
                return redirect()->back()->with('timecards', $timecards);
            } else{ // gets for the range of dates requested
                $timecards = Timecard::where('user_id', $user)
                            ->whereBetween('checkin',[$from, $to])
                            ->orderBy('checkin','DESC')
                            ->get()
                            ->groupBy(function($date) {
                                return Carbon::parse($date->checkin)->format('Y-m-d'); 
                            });
                // dd($timecards);
                return redirect()->back()->with('timecards', $timecards);
            }
        }
        // return redirect('backend.list');
    }
```

controller for the page:

```
    public function lists() {
        $users = User::all();
        return view( 'backend.list', compact('users'));
    }
```

and in the view i tried this way:

```
    @if(session()->has('timecards'))
        @foreach($timecards as $timecard)
            <div>{{$timecard->checkin}}</div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

Thank you

Update: now i get the data but it is in a json like format, any idea of how i can manipulate it?
my view:

```
    @if(session()->has('data'))
        {{session('data')}}
    @endif
```

Thankss

Answer (score 3):

In listsStore()

```
return Redirect:: route('route-name')->with( ['data' => $data] );
```

and in your route you can read it with

```
Session::get('data');
```

Comment: Thank you! now i get the data but it's a json like format, do you know how i can manipulate it so that it is more user friendly?

Comment: you can use json_decode in your view so that you will get an array.